# How to simulate multi-thread environment to do unit testing？

Tags: xcode, multithreading, unit-testing, ocunit, simulate

I am unit testing for an IPhone project based on XCode 4, Ocunit framework. I want to simulate a multi-thread environment for some cases?  How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

take a look [here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-unit-test-asynchronous-iOS-applications)

The solution is based upon use of NSRunLoop

hope help